# Plotting multiple markers on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am a newbie in android field. I have written a **android App1** that will retrieve latitude and longitude values from Network Provider and stores it in my local server(LAMP).

I have also created a MYSQL DB table that has 3 columns(lat,lon,id) that has the values (lat and lon) which are retrieved using the Network Provider. Currently there are more than 10 values in my table.

I have created JSON object for getting those values from MYSQL DB using PHP script in my **Android App2**

All these things works fine. What I have to do now is to create a MapActivity which will plot those lat and lon values on map using Marker. I tried to plot it on map but I am getting only my last location(last lat and lon value from my table) on map.

How to plot all my points on map. Following is my code which I tried but it is not working properly. Please help me to rectify my mistake.

```
public class ShowMapActivity extends MapActivity {
String returnString;
String returnString1;
double aa1 ;
double  aa2;

  private MapController mapController;
  private MapView mapView;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private MyOverlay itemizedoverlay;
  private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity


    // Configure the Map
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
      }
    });

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    itemizedoverlay = new MyOverlay(this, drawable);
    createMarker();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }
      private void createMarker() {
    GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    if (itemizedoverlay.size() > 0) {
      mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
  }



  public class GetMethodEx {

        public String getInternetData() throws Exception {

            BufferedReader in = null;
            String data = "";

            //String returnString = null;

            // httpGet

            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI website = new URI("http://192.168.1.15/latlonret1.php");
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String l = "";
                String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(l + nl);
                }
                in.close();
                data = sb.toString();
                // return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }


            // parse json data
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);


                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject json_data1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    returnString =json_data.getString("lat") + "\n";
                    returnString1 =json_data1.getString("lon") + "\n";
                    System.out.println(returnString);
                    System.out.println(returnString1);
              }

         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("stuff", returnString); 
         bundle.putString("stuff1", returnString1); 

         try
         {
             aa1=Double.valueOf(returnString);
             aa2=Double.valueOf(returnString1);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {

         }

           System.out.println(returnString);
           System.out.println(returnString1);
            }



            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return returnString;

        }  
  }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://androidcodeplace.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-multiple-markers-on-android-map.html) might be of help. There are also many example on SO too.

Comment: Actually I am not giving lat and lon values inside the code. I am trying to get it from MYSQL DB. Tat part is not working

Comment: Well, in that case
1) Get data from MySQL DB via JSON/XML
2) Parse JSON/XML and put acquired data to Arraylist
3) Loop start. Get lat,lng point from arraylist and set it into GeoPoint.
4) Create overlay item using that GeoPoint
5) add overlayitems to mapView. Loop end.

This is some code http://pastebin.com/tq357RWR

Comment: Ya i got data from MYSQL using JSON and tried to retrieve lat and lon values. But I am unable to plot all the points on the map. Only last lat and lon value is plotted on map. See my code for it. What should I change to get all values and plot it on map. Please help