# How can I get user(i.e his location) moving in google map where the updated location of user is fetch from MySql?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

I am making location based app. In my app, location of users are plotted into google map and the locations(i.e longitude, latitude) are fetched from MySql. When the locations in MySql are updated, then I want to show the updated location on google map (i.e I should see the user moving)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) which uses location data that already have latitude and longitude information needed to plot corresponding markers.

Here's a sample SQL statement that creates the table ([phpsqlajax_createtable.sql](http://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/gh-pages/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_createtable.sql)):

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966632/plotting-multiple-markers-on-google-map-in-android), you need to get data from MySQL DB via JSON/XML then parse JSON/XML and put acquired data to Arraylist. Get [latitude and longitude](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) point from arraylist then add overlayitems to mapView.

Check this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-google-maps-tutorial-google-maps-android-api/).

Comment: you are focusing how to fetch LongLat and plot them.. but my concern is toward marker animation such that I can track the user motion.